# Why isn't my hero's velocity and acceleration the same in both x directions

Tags: java

```
double horizontalVel=0;
double horizontalAcc=0;
double friction = 0.96;

public void move(){
    x += horizontalVel;
    horizontalVel *= friction;
    horizontalVel += horizontalAcc;

}

public void controlPress(int key){
    if(key==39){
        moveRight();
    }
    if(key==37){
        moveLeft();
    }

}

public void controlRelease(int key){
    if((key==39) || (key==37)){
        stop();
    }
}

public void stop(){
    horizontalAcc=0;
}


public void moveRight(){
    horizontalAcc +=0.2;
    heroImg = new ImageIcon("hero.png").getImage();     
}

public void moveLeft(){
    horizontalAcc -= 0.2;
    heroImg = new ImageIcon("heroflipped.png").getImage();      
}
```

Summarizing, I'm running a game loop where velocity and acceleration is calculated before each coordinate update. My hero takes much longer to reach a halt when moving to the left (negative x direction) than to the right. I have no idea why. The code looks perfectly symmetric to me. Is this some kind of floating point voodoo?

Comment: You should have your code print out the successive values of acceleration and velocity.  That might give you a few clues...

Comment: What's happening in the moveLeft and moveRight methods?

Comment: The important part of the code is missing :P

Comment: Does it have anything to do with how long you hold the key down before releasing? It looks like you are adding to the acceleration instead of setting it, which means if you hold the key down for a while it will take long for the velocity to reach zero (since you have no cap velocity or acceleration).

Comment: Jsdodgers: Why would that differ from left to right though?

Comment: Maybe when you went left you held the button down for longer every time and you just thought it was because of the direction.

Comment: instead of incrimneting your accelaration like `horizontalAcc += 0.2;`, try setting it like `horizontalAcc = 2;`  See if the problem persists

Comment: Jsdodgers: that's most definitely not it. However, I figured out that my hero keeps moving left even as the velocity gets asymptotically close to zero, if that is any clue.

Comment: Typecasting horizontal velocity to int before altering the x coordinate solved the problem:   x += (int)horizontalVel;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was typecasting horizontalVel to int before incrementing x:

```
    x += (int)horizontalVel;
```

For some reason, it kept rounding even arbitrarily small negative x values to -1 before typecasting, while rounding arbitrarily small positive x values to 0. Like I suspected, floating point voodoo...

Answer (score 4):

Since you already solved the issue, I do have some observations about your code:

Most important:
Do not load images at proccess logics iterations, since it will be fired 30 times per second and yours:

```
heroImg = new ImageIcon("heroflipped.png").getImage();
```

may cause several performance issues (and memory also if not well handled), prefer to load it in a constructor and reuse it when needed. Also, use ImageIO.read("heroflipped.png") that does return a BufferedImage directly.

Also, do not use literal values (hard coded constant values) to compare the controls, use the correspondent constant; since there's no guarantee that in new Java versions those values may change and you control recognition may not work as expected.

So:

```
public void controlPress(int key){
    if(key==39)
        moveRight();
    if(key==37){
        moveLeft();
}
```

Should be:

```
public void controlPress(int key){
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        moveRight();
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        moveLeft();
}
```

And, since you are creating a game, try to use Vectors (mathematical ones, not the List) to express direction and speeds as reference there's this article (that is in portuguese and you may find something in your language http://www.pontov.com.br/site/index.php/arquitetura/54-matematica-e-fisica/132-o-uso-de-vetores-nos-jogos )